# Does anyone know of a QR Code Reader library for a Windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, qr-code

We're looking to read some QR codes in a Windows 8 Metro app.  .NET libraries we've used in the past can't be referenced in WinRT/Metro and porting them won't be easy because they depend on System.Drawing which isn't in the .NET for Metro style apps.  We looked at [this](http://www.soulier.ch/?p=1275&lang=en) by Benjamin Soulier but it didn't seem to work.  Any other suggestions or something easy we're missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback from MS resources, there is nothing built in and no frameworks they were aware of yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ZXing.Net:
http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/
For Metro apps based upon HTML5/Javascript I'm currently working on a port of zxing.net for Windows Runtime Components WinMD. You can get the source from here 
https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/branches/WINMD
(btw. I'm the creator of ZXing.Net (a port of the java based ZXing))

Comment: We've moved on for now, but I'll check it out if we get back to it.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Quick way to try is by using Esponce web service. Make a simple HTTP POST request to http://www.esponce.com/api/v3/decode?format=png and send image data in body. Response should contain something like that:

```
{"content":"here goes content decoded from QR Code"}
```

Web services are platform-independent (easy to port) and lightweight on client side.

More details in [Esponce API documentation](http://www.esponce.com/help/api-v3/decode)

Comment: Thanks, but I needed something that works without a network connection.