# QR Code reading in windows 8 metro using javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, qr-code

I have been trying to decode qr codes by storing the images locally on my file system. I am trying to create a windows 8 metro app using HTML5/Javascript to do this. I could generate codes but i am having issues with decoding.

I did refer these previous threads

[Does anyone know of a QR Code Reader library for a Windows 8 Metro App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854270/does-anyone-know-of-a-qr-code-reader-library-for-a-windows-8-metro-app)

[QR Code in Windows Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706385/qr-code-in-metro-app)

and henceforth used esponce web service and made a simple HTTP-POST request to http://www.esponce.com/api/v3/decode?format=png with image data in the body, but the response was empty because of an 404 error and hence no contents were returned back. Here is the snippet with which I tried the same:

```
var picDiv = document.getElementById("picDiv");
var picturesLibrary = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary;

picturesLibrary.getFileAsync("code.bmp").then(
    function completeFile(file) {
    return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
    xhrDiv.innerText = "File Opened";
}).then(
    function completeStream(stream) {
        // Do processing. 
            var blob = MSApp.createBlobFromRandomAccessStream("image/bmp", stream);
            xhrDiv1.innerText = stream;
     return WinJS.xhr({ type: "POST", url:"http://www.esponce.com/api/v3/decode>", data: blob });
}).then(
    function (request) {
        picDiv.textContent = "uploaded file";
        picDiv.innerText = request.statusText;
        picDiv.innerText = request.status;

      }, 
    function (request) {
        picDiv.textContent = "error uploading file";
        picDiv.innerText = request.statusText;
    //    picDiv.innerText = request.statusText;
      //  picDiv.innerText = request.status;


    });
```

Kindly help me out in figuring whats wrong with the above approach.

Comment: Uh why do you use an external service for the QR code decoding? It would be better to do this locally - there is no need to waste expensive data bandwidth for this.

Comment: Locally i tried using zxing.net ported library for WinRT. But there were few other issues at runtime. Can you please suggest any other library for doing this in win8 ?

Comment: I'm currently working on a zxing.net port for Windows Runtime Components WinMD which can be use with HTML5/Javascript.
There is no pre built binary at the moment but you can get the current source from here:
https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/branches/WINMD

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 occurs only when URL does not exist otherwise there should be different error code. Problem can be diagnosed by looking at the response HTTP header **X-Api-Error**.

First, remove the '**>**' char from the URL string and add **format** parameter just in case

```
return WinJS.xhr({ type: "POST", url:"http://www.esponce.com/api/v3/decode?format=png", data: blob });
```

Then if BMP does not work try to upload a **PNG image**. Mime type should be set to **image/png**.

Alternatively you can try the Esponce API library from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Esponce.QRCode)